# Read 32-bit signed value from an "unsigned" bytestream

Tags: python, endianness, sign

I want to extract data from a file whoose information is stored in big-endian and *always* unsigned. How does the **"cast"** from *unsigned int* to *int* affect the actual decimal value? Am I correct that the most left bit decides about the whether the value is positive or negative?

I want to parse that file-format with python, and reading and unsigned value is easy:

```
def toU32(bits):
    return ord(bits[0]) << 24 | ord(bits[1]) << 16 | ord(bits[2]) << 8  | ord(bits[3])
```

but how would the corresponding *toS32* function look like?

---

Thanks for the info about the *struct*-module. But I am still interested in the solution about my actual question.

Comment: I think you want the struct module.

Comment: Used it before, but that didn't deliver the correct results. Uhm, wait, I guess I need to tell it what endianness the byte-stream has? xD

Comment: @jterrace Man, didn't know I can tell it about the endiannes.. Thanks jterrace. However, I would still be interested in the solution. :)

Comment: The Most significant bit does define the sign of the number. I know what you mean by "Left Most", but it can get confusing when talking about big endian and little endian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).

```
import struct

def toU32(bits):
    return struct.unpack_from(">I", bits)[0]

def toS32(bits):
    return struct.unpack_from(">i", bits)[0]
```

The format string, ">I", means read a big endian, ">", unsigned integer, "I", from the string bits. For signed integers you can use ">i".

**EDIT**

Had to look at another StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3831833/34329) to remember how to "convert" a signed integer from an unsigned integer in python. Though it is less of a conversion and more of reinterpreting the bits.

```
import struct

def toU32(bits):
        return ord(bits[0]) << 24 | ord(bits[1]) << 16 | ord(bits[2]) << 8  | ord(bits[3])

def toS32(bits):
    candidate = toU32(bits);
    if (candidate >> 31): # is the sign bit set?
        return (-0x80000000 + (candidate & 0x7fffffff)) # "cast" it to signed
    return candidate


for x in range(-5,5):
    bits = struct.pack(">i", x)
    print toU32(bits)
    print toS32(bits)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, didn't know that. :) However, I'd still be interested in the hard-coded version.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [struct module's](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) pack and unpack methods.

See [Endianness of integers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400012/endianness-of-integers-in-python) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The non-conditional version of toS32(bits) could be something like:

```
def toS32(bits):
    decoded = toU32(bits)
    return -(decoded & 0x80000000) + (decoded & 0x7fffffff)
```

You can pre-compute the mask for any other bit size too of course.